# How to deserialize XML element with colon?

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, xml-namespaces

i need some help regarding System.XML in C# (.NET).

I have this text somewhere inside an .xml file:

```
<Location>
    <Longitude>9.118782</Longitude>
    <Latitude>50.178153</Latitude>
    <gml:pos>104049 489104</gml:pos>
</Location>
```

Since there is a colon in the third field name, i can't use it as a variable.
Thus, my class for the deserialization (via XmlSerializer.Deserialize) looks like this:

```
public class Location
{
    public decimal Longitude { get; set; }      // this works!
    public decimal Latitude { get; set; }       // this works!

    [XmlAttribute("gml:pos")]
    public string GmlPos { get; set; }
}
```

It throws an exception. I am not very familiar with XML, but due to the exception, i figured out, that the colon stands for a XML-namespace, so i also tried these different options (all at once, of course):

```
[XmlAttribute("pos", Namespace = "gml")]
public string GmlPos { get; set; }

[XmlAttribute("pos", Namespace = "gml/")]
public string GmlPos { get; set; }

[XmlAttribute(Namespace = "gml")]
public string pos { get; set; }

[XmlAttribute(Namespace = "gml/")]
public string pos { get; set; }
```

No exception, but the field remains null. I also tried each option with XmlElement instead of XmlAttribute.

Unfortunately this is not easy to google, because the phrase 'namespace' always leads to System.XML...

Please don't suggest changing the .xml file ;)

Thankful for every help,
Tim

Comment: `XmlAttribute` expects namespace instead of prefix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gml` isn't the namespace here - it's a namespace alias. Once you've figured out what the *actual* namespace is (look for `xmlns:gml="..."`), you can specify that in XmlAttribute as per your first example. I *suspect* the namespace is http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2, in which case you'd have:

```cs
[XmlAttribute("pos", Namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2")]
public string GmlPos { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. Unfortunately, it does not work yet.

My file begins with these 3 lines, so your assumption was right:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PublicationDelivery xmlns="http://www.netex.org.uk/netex" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" version="ntx:1.1">
    <PublicationTimestamp>2022-12-12T14:00:27.451928+01:00</PublicationTimestamp>

Any more ideas?

Comment: @Timbu42 Looks like you need to set the default namespace also, to `http://www.netex.org.uk/netex`

Comment: Uh, where in my class would i do that? Sorry, am very new to XML... Thanks!

Comment: @Timbu42: "Unfortunately it does not work yet" really isn't enough information to go on. If you could provide a [mcve] - both code and data - then it would be *much* easier to help you, as we'd be able to validate fixes.

Comment: You're right, i now found the solution. Before that, the field was still null, so i didn't mention that. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -2):

I found the solution thanks to you guys, thanks a lot! :)

I start my serialization process with this code:

```
XmlSerializer xmlSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PublicationDelivery), "http://www.netex.org.uk/netex");
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(fileInNeTEx);
PublicationDelivery pd = (PublicationDelivery)xmlSer.Deserialize(reader, xmlde);
reader.Close();
```

The second parameter in the first line of code is the default namespace, i added that to the code according to the comment of Charlieface.

The Location class now looks like this:

```
public class Location
{
        public decimal Longitude { get; set; }
        public decimal Latitude { get; set; }


        [XmlElement("pos", Namespace = "http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2")]
        public string GmlPos { get; set; }


}
```